# Play sound on Android phones on Firefox when screen is off

Tags: javascript, firefox

In our company we are using a webpage in Firefox to show the tasks to be done. The wewbpage plays a sound when there is a new task. But the sound is not playing when the screen is off.
How can we solve this?
The code I use is simple. In the html file:

```
<audio id="MySound" src="/motoristes/sounds/warn.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>
```

And in the javascript:

```
document.getElementById('MySound').play();
```

Comment: Firefox is 64.0.2

Comment: I think Android shuts down Javascript when user is not on page/browser is hidden, so I don't think you can do it that way.

Comment: The point is to avoid having to create an Android app. Maybe someone knows how to be able to play a sound always.